# iteration over json objects in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am building an android application and need to make a request to an API that returns a json object and using the Volley library.

I am able to get a response but for some reason I can not iterate over the json object to receive all of the key values.
I have tried for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) but realized there is only one array in the object so the result will always be 1 so I changed it to
jsonObject.length() yet I still only get 1 result.

```
private void jsonParse(){
    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/wo1xc";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("exactMatchDomain");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("suggestedDomains");

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject suggestedDomains = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String domain = suggestedDomains.getString("domain");
                            String listPrice = suggestedDomains.getString("listPrice");

                            mTextViewResult.append(domain + ", " + listPrice + "\n\n"  );

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    mQue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("suggestedDomains");
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject suggestedDomains = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String domain = suggestedDomains.getString("domain");
        String listPrice = suggestedDomains.getString("listPrice");
        mTextViewResult.append(domain + ", " + listPrice + "\n\n"  );
}
```

Because of response:

```
{
"exactMatchDomain": {
"available": true,
"id": "domain",
"domain": "hyuirhejkyuiys.com",
"productId": 101,
"listPrice": "$13.99",
"salePrice": "$13.99",
"extendedValidation": false,
"disclaimer": null
},
"suggestedDomains": [
{
  "id": "domain",
  "domain": "hyuirhejkyuiys.net",
  "available": true,
  "productId": 12001,
  "listPrice": "$18.99",
  "salePrice": "$18.99",
  "extendedValidation": false,
  "disclaimer": null
},
{
  "id": "domain",
  "domain": "hyuirhejkyuiys.org",
  "available": true,
  "productId": 12101,
  "listPrice": "$19.99",
  "salePrice": "$9.99",
  "extendedValidation": false,
  "disclaimer": null
},
{
  "id": "domain",
  "domain": "hyuirhejkyuiys.info",
  "available": true,
  "productId": 201,
  "listPrice": "$21.99",
  "salePrice": "$4.99",
  "extendedValidation": false,
  "disclaimer": null
},
{
  "id": "domain",
  "domain": "hyuirhejkyuiys.co",
  "available": true,
  "productId": 56401,
  "listPrice": "$34.99",
  "salePrice": "$9.99",
  "extendedValidation": false,
  "disclaimer": null
},
{
  "id": "domain",
  "domain": "thehyuirhejkyuiys.com",
  "available": true,
  "productId": 101,
  "listPrice": "$13.99",
  "salePrice": "$13.99",
  "extendedValidation": false,
  "disclaimer": null
}
],
"disclaimer": "Taxes and ICANN fee not included in price 
displayed.\n*Additional charges and registration restrictions may apply."
}
```

> I recommend to you use the Retrofit 2 instead of the Volley.

Comment: I have tried this, however `JSONObject suggestedDomains = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` Still only returns 1 result. I will look into Retrofit but I have a feeling it is not because of the library I am just not understanding what to do with the json object when I get the response.

Comment: You get the response string. Just parse it. Look what you got in debug watchers.

Comment: did you change loop? for(int i = 0; i <`jsonArray`.length(); i++) {

Comment: Ovdiien, yes I changed the loop to jsonArray.length but only works if I change the key to `JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("suggestedDomains");` This still only displays 1 result I am assuming because there is only 1 json array. I cant figure out how to loop through the hole object including the array.

Comment: Oh, you may use Iterator and loop through an Object including Array

Comment: I appreciate your help. I deleted the whole project and started over its now working. The only thing I can think of is maybe I had a mistake somewhere else in my code. I am marking your answer as correct because it is correct. But I still dont know why this didnt work before.